# Angular 2 splitting one big route to two routes

Tags: angular

I'm using the new router and I decided to split my big route, one for all of the application, into 2 routes.

This is what I did:

1. **Create a new route and module:** `guests.routes.ts`, `guests.module.ts`
2. **Removed** the components from my `app.routes.ts` & `app.module.ts`. Those filese had all the routes and components in them.
3. Refreshed my app and got:

   `Uncaught Type LoginComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: GuestsModule and AppModule!`

My LoginComponent is one of the components I moved from my `app.module.ts` to my `guests.module.ts`.

Those is my guests.module.ts declrations:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    IntroComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent
  ],
```

What could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to export `LoginComponent` from `guests.module.ts`.

```
    @NgModule({
        ...
        exports: [ LoginComponent ]
    })
```

Read more about Modules and exports [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you. What I can do in case that both of the modules uses the same component?

Comment: That's what feature Modules are for, you may create a Module with all your common components exported , and then import wherever needed, Cheers!

Comment: If you are not importing Component\Module where you are using it, you will get the issue. Ideally if you are using same component in multiple Modules, they should go into some common Module.

Comment: My common module is `AppModule`. I declared my `InfoComponent`, which is the common component, in my `AppModule`. My `GuestModule` and my `MembersModule` are using this component. how I can declare that?

Comment: By the name of it, it sounds `AppModule` will be your main bootstrapped module, and you would be importing `GuestsModule` and `MembersModule` into it, now if you import AppModule into GuestModule it will create a circular dependency and will error out. You can put `InfoComponent` into some other 4th Module and import it in `GuestsModule` and `MembersModule`, which in turn will be imported into AppModule, Make sense?

Comment: I appreciate your help here and descriptive comments, thank you again! I have router error in my GuestModule, `Type RouterOutlet is part of the declarations of 2 modules: RouterModule and GuestsModule!`, while in my GuestModule I have only linked to it's route file: `import { guestsRouting } from './guests.routing';`, This modulese annoyed me to hell

Comment: You're welcome!! By any chance you are adding directives using RouterOutlet\ROUTE_DIRECTIVE in any your `GuestModule`? If you are you don't have to.